# loop to print out list in increasing order

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the list like this by looping though a nested list.

```
1: 1 1
2: 1 2, 2 1
3: 1 3, 2 2, 3 1
4: 1 4, 2 3, 3 2, 4 1
5: 2 4, 3 3, 4 2
```

and so on..

Here is my attempt at it:
I have looped though each list and was able to print out the list. I am not sure how to loop though the next list in an increasing order until it reaches the end.

```
val = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [2, [1,2,3,4]], [3, [1,2,3,4]], [4, [1,2,3,4]]]
k = 0
for i in range(0,4):
    k += 1
    for j in range (0,4):
        print(k,":", val[i][0],val[i][1][j])
        k+= 1



1 : 1 1
2 : 1 2
3 : 1 3
4 : 1 4
6 : 2 1
7 : 2 2
8 : 2 3
9 : 2 4
11 : 3 1
12 : 3 2
13 : 3 3
14 : 3 4
16 : 4 1
17 : 4 2
18 : 4 3
19 : 4 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path except instead of printing the values you are getting in the first set of for loops store them in a dictionary with lists as values and the sum of the two values as the key. Due to the order of the original list I did not need to sort the lists in the dictionary.

Later when printing you will join the values together which is why I formatted them before I added them to their list. The format will add an extra comma to each row which is why I added the `[:-1]` to the join to remove it.

```
from collections import defaultdict 

val = [[1, [1,2,3,4]], [2, [1,2,3,4]], [3, [1,2,3,4]], [4, [1,2,3,4]]]
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range (0,4):
         d[val[i][0]+val[i][1][j]].append('{} {},'.format(val[i][0],val[i][1][j]))

for x,i in enumerate(d):
    #If it needs to be sorted just add sorted(d[i]) in place of d[i]
    s = ' '.join(d[i])[:-1]         
    print('{}: {}'.format(x+1, s))

1: 1 1
2: 1 2, 2 1
3: 1 3, 2 2, 3 1
4: 1 4, 2 3, 3 2, 4 1
5: 2 4, 3 3, 4 2
6: 3 4, 4 3
7: 4 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to do this recursively? This is part of a bigger project which updates coordinates from the list on canvas using tkinter. @SirParselot

Comment: @Abhi I can't think of a way to do that but I'm not very good at recursive functions. Why does it matter if this is recursive?

Comment: I have to use the values from the list to update/add a coordinate on canvas continuously. It doesn't have to be recursive but using different method will help to update coordinates.

Comment: Could you store your values a different way, possibly as a coordinate?